# Given an HDC, how can I determine what the name of the application is?

Tags: windows, gdi

I have an HDC object and I'd like to use it to get the name of the program that created it (such as Notepad or Firefox). Is there a way to do this?

If not, how can I do this?

Comment: perhaps a bit more context. How is it that your "application" is getting 'sent' an HDC from some other random app?

Comment: It's given it as an argument. I'm maintaining some code and can only change a certain part of it, which is only given as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [WindowFromDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145201(VS.85).aspx) to get the window handle from the HDC
2. [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) to get the process ID from the window handle
3. [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) to obtain a process handle from the process ID
4. [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217(VS.85).aspx) to obtain the program's path from the process handle

Or, once you have the window handle, [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx) to get the window title.